# On click except one child with class + use of this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I could define a click event in jQuery / JavaScript which excludes children with a specific class. In the same time I need to use "this" to access the clicked element.

```js
$(".slidebox-header *:not(.stop)").click(function(event) {
  alert("woohoo!");
  $(this).siblings(".slidebox-content").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.slidebox-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.stop {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidebox">
  <div class="slidebox-header">
    <div class="stop">BLOCKED AREA</div>
    <span>Header - Click allowed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slidebox-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But because "this" refers to the children of ".slidebox-header", it is not working.

My question: Is there an elegant way to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slidebox-content` is a sibling of `slidebox-header`, so use `.closest()` to traverse to to header then use `.sibling()`

```
$(".slidebox-header *:not(.stop)").click(function(event) {
  $(this).closest('.slidebox-header').siblings(".slidebox-content").slideToggle();
});
```

Also you can use descendant selector to target the specific child.

```
$(".slidebox-header > span").click(function(event) {
  $(this).closest('.slidebox-header').siblings(".slidebox-content").slideToggle();
});
```

```js
$(".slidebox-header *:not(.stop)").click(function(event) {
  //alert("woohoo!");
  $(this).closest('.slidebox-header').siblings(".slidebox-content").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.slidebox-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.stop {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidebox">
  <div class="slidebox-header">
    <div class="stop">BLOCKED AREA</div>
    <span>Header - Click allowed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slidebox-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or you could bind event with header and use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) with block element to stop event bubbling.

```
$(".slidebox-header").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".slidebox-content").slideToggle();
});
$(".slidebox-header .stop").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$(".slidebox-header").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".slidebox-content").slideToggle();
});
$(".slidebox-header .stop").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.slidebox-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.stop {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidebox">
  <div class="slidebox-header">
    <div class="stop">BLOCKED AREA</div>
    <span>Header - Click allowed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slidebox-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working. But now it does not fire if I click on ".sidebox-header" iteself. Any way to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parents()` or `closest()` to achieve this. Below is the usage of `parents()`:

```js
$(".slidebox-header *:not(.stop)").click(function(event) {
  alert("woohoo!");
  $(this).parents(".slidebox:first").find(".slidebox-content").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.slidebox-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.stop {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidebox">
  <div class="slidebox-header">
    <div class="stop">BLOCKED AREA</div>
    <span>Header - Click allowed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slidebox-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```